# Does PostgreSQL guarantee unique timestamps?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

8-byte integers [are now the default](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/datatype-datetime.html) for Postgres 8.4, so it allows microsecond values to be stored.

I don't care too much about real microsecond precision (probably depends on OS capabilities?!) - But does Postgres guarantee, that the timestamp values (inserted by `current_timestamp`) are always different between any two transactions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No.

I did a small test, inserting `current_timestamp` from 5 parallell clients in a table, 3 of 3463 records got the same timestamp.

Comment: Ok, that's the definite answer - I'll have to look for a different solution then. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, precision depends on the OS. Within a single transaction the timestamps are all the same when using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, when using CLOCK_TIMESTAMP they might be different. Different transactions can have different CURRENT_TIMESTAMPS, depends on how fast you can insert/update.

If you need uniqueness, add a unique constraint.

Comment: The unique constraint is a good idea, but one transaction can insert multiple instances in a table - so it would violate the uniqueness. It's ok for my application to have the same timestamp, but not when inserted by different transactions.

Comment: Do some tests to see if you can insert/update fast enough to get problems.

Comment: Yeah, this is really a situation, where I'd have a simple, super-fast solution (for the version management in my distributed app), but at the price of a small chance of errors. Or on the other hand a solution, which would make the app much slower, and increase traffic by a significant factor - but it would be more correct...

Answer (score 1):

Even if it does, it seems dangerous to rely on the values being unique. If you need a unique key you are better off using an alternative such as a `serial` column.

Comment: I'd love to do that - but my use case seems to require that: I want to use a version field in JPA that is globally at least mostly ascending, to improve performance (not just within an entity). But JPA unfortunately doesn't allow me to use a serial column, a sequence or a sequence table for a version field. But it does allow me to use a timestamp, and with JPA, I can safely assume the version field to be ascending (for an entity), as long as the database guarantees uniqueness.

Answer (score 1):

Luckily no, since that would mean a "please make this slower than it has to be" option.

If you really need what is really a serial, but which looks like a timestamp, then add some microseconds on based on the result of a serial!

Comment: Good point, and a good idea. I wish, JPA would allow me to do that (it manages the timestamps for version fields itself).

Comment: Why does it insist that a version is unique. That seems like it's doing two jobs from the same thing. Could you add your own version and identity columns yourself and ignore this version+identity feature?

Comment: @Jon: I hope, I'll find a way to extend/replace JPA's versioning with my own versioning, but I don't think it's easy to do, because it's an integral part of JPA.

Comment: Do JPA have a way where they completely manage versioning themselves? In which case, just use an integral type.

Comment: @Jon: Yes, JPA offers integral versioning and timestamp versioning. The problem with integral versioning is, that JPA starts counting at 1 for every entity in the table separately. So I can't do a query `from t where version > 578`, when I want to retrieve all entities that have changed since the last time I checked. Using a sequence (or setting the value myself) would be great, but JPA doesn't seem to allow that.

Comment: That's a different requirement to versioning though (though slightly overlapping, and sometimes we can do both from the same value). Maybe have a version and a last-mod as separate columns?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the recommendation of adding a serial. But if what you are trying to do doesn't merit a schema change, you could use the system column xmin to separate rows with the same timestamp but from different transactions.

```
  SELECT ts, xmin, count(1)
  FROM foo
  GROUP BY ts, xmin
```